# Get list of values from vector of hashmap using filter or for

Tags: clojure

I'm quite new to clojure and have been struggling to understand how things work exactly. I have a vector of hashmaps as such, titled authors:

```
------ Authors -----------
[{:id 100, :name "Albert Einstein", :interest "Physics"}
 {:id 200, :name "Alan Turing", :interest "Computer Science"}
 {:id 300, :name "Jeff Dean", :interest "Programming"}]
```

I want to write a function that takes the id, and returns a list of the corresponding author names. I have two options for doing so: using filter or using for loop.

When using filter, I have a predicate function already that returns true if the author has matching id:

```
(defn check-by-id [author id]
    (if (= id (:id author)) true false))
```

But I'm not sure how to use this in order to get the list of author names when passing the id.

Comment: Not sure how can you have more than a single author. Can the list contain more than a single entry for the same id?

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure it can since I later on have to implement a function that adds an author to the map. But I'm given the authors vector as it is described above

Comment: I've found a way to use a for loop to iterate over the names of the authors, but now I want to append that name to a list 'y' only when the id matches the id of an author in the hashmap.

Comment: Try to put in an entire solution you made, so we can help with more specific questions. If you ask on "how to do that", I can refer you to the [reduce](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce) function, which allows you to aggregate results while iterating over the input.

Comment: You can drop the `if` form: `(defn check-by-id [author id] (= id (:id author)))`. If you want a structure you can append to, use a vector.

Comment: Are you sure you are not given a sequence or collection of `id`s? That would make a good exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Three other ways via [`keep`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/keep), [`for`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/for) and [`reduce`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/reduce):

```clj
(keep (fn [{:keys [id name]}] (when (= id 100) name)) authors)
;; => ("Albert Einstein")

(for [{:keys [id name]} authors 
      :when (= id 100)] 
  name)
;; => ("Albert Einstein")

(reduce (fn [v {:keys [id name]}] 
          (if (= id 100) (conj v name) v)) 
        [] 
        authors)
;; => ["Albert Einstein"]
```

I prefer `for` (with `:when`) since it's shortest and in my eyes most clear. `reduce` I find best when you want to build a specific type of collection, this case a vector.

Answer (score 0):

`Filter` will filter the list of maps. But the result is still a `sequence of maps`. You can `map` or `reduce` the result to get the list of authors.

```
(def authors [{:id 100, :name "Albert Einstein", :interest "Physics"}
          {:id 100, :name "Richard Fynmann", :interest "Physics"}
          {:id 200, :name "Alan Turing", :interest "Computer Science"}
          {:id 300, :name "Jeff Dean", :interest "Programming"}])

(defn check-by-id [author id] (= id (:id author)))

(defn filter-ids [id col] (filter #(check-by-id % id) col))

(filter-ids 100 authors)
;; ↪ ({:id 100, :name "Albert Einstein", :interest "Physics"}
;;     {:id 100, :name "Richard Fynmann", :interest "Physics"})


(map :name (filter-ids 100 authors))
;; ↪ ("Albert Einstein" "Richard Fynmann")
```

Comment: It worked! Thank you so much! I was unfamiliar with the # and % symbols and what they can be used for.

Comment: @QuintessentialGamer, I'm sorry I missed your question! `#` is used to create an Anonymous function and `%1`, `%2` are it's parameters. `%` can be used instead of `%1`

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `group-by` for this task:

```clj
(def list-of-maps
  [{:id 100, :name "Albert Einstein", :interest "Physics"}
   {:id 200, :name "Alan Turing", :interest "Computer Science"}
   {:id 300, :name "Jeff Dean", :interest "Programming"}])

(map :name (get (group-by :id list-of-maps) 100))
;; => ("Albert Einstein")
```